# How to prompt and wait for next command in order to continue

Tags: objective-c

I've created a command line tool that parses JSON from reddit's front page.  After being able to successfully list all of the submission titles; I want to be able to prompt and wait for numeric selection to go deeper into the post.

Btw, I'm fairly new to the language and I'm creating this for fun.  I don't really know how to even properly ask this question because I've never developed for a compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about plain ol' C:

```
int selection;
do
{
    fseek(stdin, 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("Select and ID: ");
}
while (scanf("%i", &selection) == 0);
```

Sorry that I have no method for you to check out. However, you may at your discretion read the man page for `scanf` (and for `fseek`, now that I added it— sorry for the non-working snippet earlier!). If you want a small exercise, try to find out why it's necessary to have the `fseek` call.

Though don't forget to `#include <stdio.h>`.